# Find the working set a project is assigned to

Tags: eclipse

I want to find out to which working sets a project is assigned to in my workspace. I don't want to get all the working sets from the `WorkingSetManager` and browse through all the working sets. That takes to much time.

Is there another way to find the 'parents' of a project ?

Thank you

PS: I need to do this programatically

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the project and click on the "Assign Working Sets..." it should have the working set(s) that it belongs to already checked off in the pop-up.

Comment: Maybe my question was not clearly formulated. I need to find the working set parents programmatically. I am writing a plug-in that will manipulate projects in the workspace.